# What connector is this on an LED strip light?

Tags: led, connector, identification, led-strip

I managed to find some scrap LED strips. I noticed that these have some peculiar connectors on them.

Does anyone recognise what connectors these are?

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score -1):

The plastic housing is most likely proprietary, on the inside (bad picture) it looks like a 0.1" header

[image]
Take a look [here](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity-AMP/3-644457-4?qs=dPWvNUObvpp5NdNNhAWVZA%3D%3D&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI99_13-_A4QIV1x-tBh2fOAfcEAQYASABEgLaPvD_BwE).

Comment: Cheers laptop2d and SamGibson.
Labmat

Comment: Headers are square terminals as opposed to these round ones.

Comment: I have those similar lights, the ones on mine were 0.1" headers.